# How to use the value of a variable instead of number

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want to make an embed in which i can change the color in. Is there a way to use the value of a variable instead of the color code?
Like color=colorVar instead of color=0x00f531.

```
embed=discord.Embed(title="Server Status", color=0x00f531)
embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://img.icons8.com/clouds/100/000000/checkmark--v2.png")
embed.add_field(name="Spieler", value="query", inline=False)
```

Comment: `color=colorVar` should work fine assuming you have a `colorVar` variable set prior that holds a valid value. What's the problem?

Comment: Yes. What happened when you tried.